# localhost/mediawiki-1.30.0/ in browser returns run(); in Firefox and file content in Chromium

Tags: apache2, php, mediawiki

After updating from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 my Wiki stopped working.

My system looks like:

```
~$ ls /var/www/html/mediawiki-1.30.0/
api.php                     img_auth.php             phpcs.xml
autoload.php                includes                 profileinfo.php
cache                       index.php                README
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md          INSTALL                  RELEASE-NOTES-1.30
composer.json               jsduck.json              resources
composer.local.json-sample  languages                serialized
COPYING                     load.php                 skins
CREDITS                     LocalSettings.php        StartProfiler.sample
docs                        LocalSettings.php~       tests
extensions                  maintenance              thumb_handler.php
FAQ                         mediawiki-1.30.0         thumb.php
Gruntfile.js                mediawiki-1.30.0.tar.gz  UPGRADE
HISTORY                     mw-config                vendor
images                      opensearch_desc.php
```

and directing Firefox to `http://localhost/mediawiki-1.30.0/` makes it display `run();` whereas Chromium displays:

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the main web entry point for MediaWiki.
 *
 * If you are reading this in your web browser, your server is probably
 * not configured correctly to run PHP applications!
 *
 * See the README, INSTALL, and UPGRADE files for basic setup instructions
 * and pointers to the online documentation.
 *
 * https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/MediaWiki
 *
 * ----------
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along
 * with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc.,
 * 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
 * http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
 *
 * @file
 */

// Bail on old versions of PHP, or if composer has not been run yet to install
// dependencies. Using dirname( __FILE__ ) here because __DIR__ is PHP5.3+.
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart MediaWiki.Usage.DirUsage.FunctionFound
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/PHPVersionCheck.php';
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
wfEntryPointCheck( 'index.php' );

require __DIR__ . '/includes/WebStart.php';

$mediaWiki = new MediaWiki();
$mediaWiki->run();
```

I had this happen before and I got an answer that solved the problem. However, I can not find the answer any longer, thus I must ask the question again.

I think the answer was a configuration item but which? Configuration of apache2, php7.2 or mediawiki?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling php for Apache2

```
sudo a2enmod php
```

and restarting Apache2

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

solved the problem.

Comment: This was my first thought when I read the beginning of the question. Please accept your own answer.